# Why my dataTables does not appear using $.each inside function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have nested array json object (Layer 1, Layer 2 and Layer 3). My problem is dataTables does not appear. Any related CDN has been imported. The table just only display `<thead>` section. I have referred many websites, but it did not solve my problem.

Earlier I was using standard table to display the values inside Layer 3 json using `<tbody>`, `<tr>` and `<td>`, do the result is successful. But now I removed all that and try to use dataTable as I need its' features.

I successfully displayed value id for Layer 1 and Layer 2. But for my case below, it is unsuccessfully to display Layer 3 information (l3_id, l3_name, etc..) in dataTables.

[image]

**JSON**

```
{
    "status": "Success",
    "data": [{
        "project_id": "1",
        "project_name": "project name",
        "l1_task": [{
            "l1_id": "1",
            "l1_name": "Layer 1",
            "l2_task": [{
                "l2_id": "1",
                "l2_name": "Layer 2",
                "l3_task": [{
                        "l3_id": "1",
                        "l3_name": "Layer 3.1"
                    },
                    {
                        "l3_id": "2",
                        "l3_name": "Layer 3.2"
                    }
                ]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    loadtable();

    $('#Layer3Table').DataTable({
        ajax: {
            url: "exampleData/activity.json"
        },
        columns: [{
                data: "l1_task.0.l2_task.0.l3_task.0.l3_id"
            },
            {
                data: "l1_task.0.l2_task.0.l3_task.0.l3_name"
            }
        ],
    });

    function loadtable() {
        var project = '';
        $.ajax({
            url: url_project_detail,
            crossDomain: true,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: "data",
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.status == "Success") {
                    // Layer 1 array object
                    $.each(response.data[0].l1_task, function(key, value) {
                        project +=
                            "<div>" +
                            "<div>";
                        // Layer 2 array object
                        $.each(value.l2_task, function(key, value) {
                            project +=
                                "<div>" +
                                "<div>" +
                                // Layer 3 array object
                                "<div class='table-responsive'>" +
                                "<table id='Layer3Table' class='table table-striped' style='width:100%'>" +
                                "<thead>" +
                                "<tr>" +
                                "<th class='text-center'>ID</th>" +
                                "<th class='text-center'>Activity Name</th>" +
                                "</tr>" +
                                "</thead>" +
                                "</table>" +
                                "</div>";
                        }); // for Layer 2
                        project += "</div>" + "</div>";
                    }); // for Layer 1
                    $("#projectDetail2").append(project);
                } else {}
            },
            error: function(e) {}
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: You are not closing two of your DIV elements,  is that intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got the solution by removing this dataTables.

```
$('#Layer3Table').DataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: "exampleData/activity.json"
    },
    columns: [{
            data: "l1_task.0.l2_task.0.l3_task.0.l3_id"
        },
        {
            data: "l1_task.0.l2_task.0.l3_task.0.l3_name"
        }
    ],
});
```

and initiate dataTables at this section

```
}); // for Layer 1
    $("#projectDetail2").append(project);
    $('#Layer3Table').DataTable();
} else {}
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Nice job on figuring this one out on your own, OP.   I will include the solution in my answer as well.

You were appending the table after calling datatables so it makes sense you would need to put the call to datatables after appending the table with the data in it.   I should have caught that,  nice job!

---

Your success function does not loop through l3_task.   Try this ..

```
success: function(response) {
    if (response.status == "Success") {
        // Layer 1 array object
        $.each(response.data[0].l1_task, function(key, value) {
            project +=
                "<div>" +
                "<div>";
            // Layer 2 array object
            $.each(value.l2_task, function(key1, value1) {
                project +=
                    "<div>" +
                    "<div>" +
                    // Layer 3 array object
                    "<div class='table-responsive'>" +
                    "<table id='Layer3Table' class='table table-striped' style='width:100%'>" +
                    "<thead>" +
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<th class='text-center'>ID</th>" +
                    "<th class='text-center'>Activity Name</th>" +
                    "</tr>" +
                    "</thead>";
                $.each(value1.l3_task, function(k, v) {
                    project +=
                        "<tr>" +
                        "<td>" + v.l3_id + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + v.l3_name + "</td>" +
                        "</tr>";
                });
                project +=
                    "</table>" +
                    "</div>";
            }); // for Layer 2
            project += "</div></div></div></div>";
        }); // for Layer 1
        $("#projectDetail2").append(project);
        $('#Layer3Table').DataTable();
    } else {}
},
```

Comment: I have tried this before, it is successful but the dataTables features is not appear such as search box, etc as my post above.

Comment: @mastersuse If dataTables is not working it could be due to error.  Are you getting anything in the console?

Comment: please find my finding below. it solved my problem.